# How to get last deselected item from multiple select

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have 2 select elements, that i set second multiple select's items with first select's selected option value.

I bind values to second select that is multiple type. I am tracking selected items' values in a hidden because if user selects first select element's another option, second select is bound different option values.

1- Select element with Category Group Values

2- Multiple select element with Category Values

For example first select is category group, when a user selects category group, i bind categories of that group into multiple select element. Let's say user selected groups with id 1,4,5,7. I set them in a hidden field as comma separated values. If user selects another category group, I bind that group's categories to multiple select element. Let's say user selected categories 11,15,18. Current hidden value is "1,4,5,7,11,15,18".
But then deselected 15 from it. I have to set hidden field's value to: "1,4,5,7,11,18". But i cannot detect which option is deselected. Is there a way to detect it in any ways?

Maybe a better algorithm I should use. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The hidden field seems unnecessary. It just mirrors, in a different form, the state of the multiple select element. If you need the x,y,z,... string for whatever reason, then it can be built on-the-fly every time it is needed rather than keeping a ready-made mirror.

Comment: Let's say I have a category group with vals x,y,z. If user selects x, then second select element is bound 1,2,3. Then user checks 1 and 3. If user selects another category group named y. Then new categories with id's 4,5,6 are bound to second select. Then user selects 5,6. I want to submit 1,3,5,6 to server but my current second select has 5,6 only checked. That is why I use a hidden field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the multiple select box to checkboxlist, this way i can track select/unselect changes of each item individually. Then if unchecked, remove from hidden values or if checked add value to list. This is a better approach to do what I am doing exactly.